# Android Altbeacon Library; scanning is not working as should

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am working on an Android application that requires to scan for a set of beacons. The default configuration for the foreground scanning indicates that in a time interval of 10 seconds, 10 scan cycles will be performed; since

```
DEFAULT_FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD = 1100L;
```

In the first phase, I was scanning for a set of beacons with a list of mac addresses in this way:

```
public void startScanningRegions(){
  try {
    Region region = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < beaconsMacAddresses.size(); i++){
        region = new Region("region_" + i,beaconsMacAddresses.get(i));
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    }
  } catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }    
}

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Collected beacons size: " + beacons.size());
                }
            }
        }); 
        startScanningRegions();
    }
```

This approach is working very well, i.e. each callback correspons to a certain region, and contains a non-empty list of collected beacons, its usually one item because the default scan period is 1.1 second and the beacon transmission frequence is 1 /s.

However, the number of beacons I am going to use in my application will be a huge number and its nut efficient to scan for them by creating new region for each beacon, I found that the common UUID may help. So I updated my scanning code to be like this:

```
public void startScanningRegions(){
        Region region1 = new Region("uuid_region", Identifier.parse(ConstantStrings.AXA_BEACON_UUID),null,null);
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region1);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem appears here. In a time interval of 10 seconds, about 10 callbacks are being called, each of them contains 2-3 beacons at most, i.e. each beacon is now being collected once or twice in the 10 seconds interval, however it was being collected 7-8 times by the mac_address region.

I need to catch each beacon that is in range, at least 5-6 times / 10 seconds in order my login to work. How can I improve that ?

Comment: Do the beacons each have a different identifier?  Or are some of them the same?

Comment: Definitely each one has its unique identifier. Actually I am still debugging and analyzing what's going on. The problem might be in the beacons transmission, or in the battery of some of them,  because when I replaced them and modified the frequencies of the new ones I got a list of size 2 or 3 beacons in each callback.